# Performance issues with Open Data Cube when `find_datasets` with a lot of results

Tags: amazon-web-services, open-data-cube

Our ODC instance is deployed on AWS Aurora RDS and is populated with approximately 200 million datasets. The Aurora RDS is configured as Serverless v2 (64 - 128 ACUs) and has 4 replicas (1 writer + 3 readers) in total.

datacube version = 1.8.12

I am facing issues with its performance, especially when I'm attempting to `find_datasets` that would return more than a few 10s of thousands datasets.

As an example, a `find_datasets` search generates the following query:

```sql
SELECT agdc.dataset.id, agdc.dataset.metadata_type_ref, agdc.dataset.dataset_type_ref, agdc.dataset.metadata, agdc.dataset.archived, agdc.dataset.added, agdc.dataset.added_by, array((SELECT selected_dataset_location.uri_scheme || ':' || selected_dataset_location.uri_body AS anon_1 
FROM agdc.dataset_location AS selected_dataset_location 
WHERE selected_dataset_location.dataset_ref = agdc.dataset.id AND selected_dataset_location.archived IS NULL ORDER BY selected_dataset_location.added DESC, selected_dataset_location.id DESC)) AS uris 
FROM agdc.dataset 
WHERE agdc.dataset.archived IS NULL AND (tstzrange(least(agdc.common_timestamp((agdc.dataset.metadata #>> '{properties, dtr:start_datetime}')), agdc.common_timestamp((agdc.dataset.metadata #>> '{properties, datetime}'))), greatest(agdc.common_timestamp((agdc.dataset.metadata #>> '{properties, dtr:end_datetime}')), agdc.common_timestamp((agdc.dataset.metadata #>> '{properties, datetime}'))), '[]') && tstzrange('2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, '2023-05-31T23:59:59.999999+00:00'::timestamptz, '[]')) AND agdc.dataset.dataset_type_ref = 72
```

A `SELECT COUNT (*) ...` relevant query (same search parameters) will show about 8 million records returned.

The related database session gets a `IO: DataFileRead` wait event and stays there for a long time. I don't know if it completes since either datacube gets killed or I simply kill the process after a lot of time (maybe more than 1 h).

If I copy-paste the generated query to pgAdmin and execute it directly from my computer, I'm getting a ClientWrite event.

I'm not sure if this is a datacube/sqlalchemy issue or a postgres issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty unusual use case to select 8 million datasets.

I'd rethink your architecture a bit, and break your analysis down, or if you really want to interrogate that many datasets, perhaps go direct to Postgres or dump to a bulk format to explore. Something like Parquet would work.

What I expect is happening is that this query is happily churning away and slowly returning the 8 million rows, but it's timing out because the code that has been written in Datacube expects something in seconds, not minutes or an hour!

You *could* explore the bottleneck, whether it's the database, the network or the Python code, but I reckon re-thinking what you're doing is a better idea.

Comment: My use case does NOT involve returning 8 million datasets. The issue above is regarding a limitation when querying my ODC instance where the returned Dataset objects exceed a few tens of thousands. I'm not sure how to determine how unusual this use case is but I doesn't seem like an exceptional one.

EDIT: It's been a while since this issue was posted. We have decided to drop ODC because of its poor performance and its high costs, in favor of a custom solution involving NoSQL.